# Computing $Var [E(y(x))]$ where $\text{logit} y(x)\sim N(\mu(x), \sigma^2(x) + \lambda^2)$

Tags: bayesian, logistic, variance, gaussian-process

I have a computationally expensive stochastic computer model, $y(x)$ which outputs values on $(0,1)$ and want to use a Gaussian process as a surrogate for $y(x)$. Since $0<y(x)<1$ it would be sensible to take a prior of the form $\text{logit } y(\cdot) \sim GP(m(\cdot), C(\cdot, \cdot) + \lambda^2I)$ with, say, $C(x, x') = \alpha^2 \exp\left(-\frac{1}{\theta^2}(x - x')^2\right)$ is a covariance function and $\lambda^2$ is the 'nugget' term which account for noise in the simulations.

We can then observe some data and perform posterior inference. Conditional on the GP hyperparameters ($\alpha, \theta, \lambda$) the posterior moments of $\text{logit}\,y(x)$ are available via the multivariate normal conditional distribution formuae. Let the posterior mean and variance of $E(\text{logit}\, y(x))$ be $\mu(x)$ and $\sigma^2(x)$. The posterior mean and variance for $\text{logit}\, y(x)$ are then denoted $\mu(x)$ and $\sigma^2(x) + \lambda^2$.

From this framework I can find $E(y(x)) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\text{expit }(\theta)N(\theta; \mu(x), \sigma^2(x) + \lambda^2) \text{d}\theta$. Similarly, $Var(y(x)) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\text{expit }(\theta)^2 N(\theta; \mu(x), \sigma^2(x) + \lambda^2) \text{d}\theta - E(y(x))^2$. This variance term accounts for two sources of uncertainty:

(i) The stochastic nature of the computer model
(ii) My lack of knowledge about the computer model

Now my question is: How can I isolate the uncertainty due to (ii)? I would like to find $Var( E(y(x)))$. We can assume all the GP hyperparameters take fixed values. In particular I would like a deterministic method for calculation, be it exact or approximate.

---

Notation: $\text{logit}\,(p) = \log(p) - \log(1-p)$. $\text{expit}\,(q) = (1 + \exp(-q))^{-1}$.